# Bootstrap select dropdown gets distorted when used with slick slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, slick.js

When using [Bootstrap select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select) dropdown with the [slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) slider, it gets distorted.

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/01ncvrbj/) to jsfiddle. 
HTML code:

```
<div class="slider">
<select name="test" multiple="" class="selectpicker">
  <option value="Created" data-subtext="">Created (91)</option>
  <option value="Approved" data-subtext="">Approved (6038)</option>
  <option value="Completed" data-subtext="">Completed (477)</option>
   <option value="Held" data-subtext="">Held (54)</option>
   <option value="Rejected" data-subtext="">Rejected (4)</option>
   <option value="Cancelled" data-subtext="">Cancelled (71)</option>
   <option value="Authorized" data-subtext="">Authorized (1)</option>
</select>
<select name="test" multiple="" class="selectpicker">
  <option value="Created" data-subtext="">Created (91)</option>
  <option value="Approved" data-subtext="">Approved (6038)</option>
  <option value="Completed" data-subtext="">Completed (477)</option>
   <option value="Held" data-subtext="">Held (54)</option>
   <option value="Rejected" data-subtext="">Rejected (4)</option>
   <option value="Cancelled" data-subtext="">Cancelled (71)</option>
   <option value="Authorized" data-subtext="">Authorized (1)</option>
</select>
<select name="test" multiple="" class="selectpicker">
  <option value="Created" data-subtext="">Created (91)</option>
  <option value="Approved" data-subtext="">Approved (6038)</option>
  <option value="Completed" data-subtext="">Completed (477)</option>
   <option value="Held" data-subtext="">Held (54)</option>
   <option value="Rejected" data-subtext="">Rejected (4)</option>
   <option value="Cancelled" data-subtext="">Cancelled (71)</option>
   <option value="Authorized" data-subtext="">Authorized (1)</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var slickEle = jQuery(".slider").slick();
    slickEle.slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      variableWidth: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      touchMove : true,
      mobileFirst: true
    })
});
```

Steps to reproduce the problem

Click on the select box it gets distorted.
[image]

What is the expected behaviour?

Without Slick:
[image]

What is observed behaviour?

With Slick:
[image]

====================================================================

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question on bootstrap-select issue tracker as well: [#2314](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2314).
As answered by [Casey Holzer](https://github.com/caseyjhol):

> You need to set container: 'body' or data-container="body".
>   https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#container

As per Container documentation:

> Append the select menu to a specific element, e.g. container: 'body'
>   or data-container=".main-content". This is useful if the select
>   element is inside an element with overflow: hidden.

Select element is inside slick-list which sets `overflow: hidden` so that only current slides are visible, so when we set the container: body it works.

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/01ncvrbj/4/

Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
 .slick-list {
     overflow: unset;
}
```

Comment: This( .slick-list) css class is belongs to  slick plugin. You have to override its css property from "overflow:hidden" to "overflow:unset".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this will make the hidden slides visible